# Update a Price field based a factor in another

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables a '`price`' table

```
id   | country_id |sell_price
-----+------------+----------
123  |  321       |      5.00
```

and a exchange '`rate`' table

```
country_id | rate
-----------+------
321        | 1.05
```

I need to *update* `price.sell_price` by multiplying `price.sell_price * rate.rate where country_id = 321`

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE price p, rate r
SET p.sell_price = p.sell_price*r.rate
WHERE p.country_id=r.country_id
AND r.country_id=321
```

Documentation: [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Comment: perfect thank! - now i can stop hitting my head against the desk!